# Complex reverse proxy

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy

I'm looking for a one-liner. The hops are:

1. I have a Ubuntu instance with SSH exposed to the internet
2. Only a single user with a key can SSH from the internet.
3. That single user has zero privileges, so once in I must switch users
4. Once users are switched, I can create a reverse proxy for port 123

I can't seem to figure out how to compact these steps in to a one-liner such that I can access port 123 on the Ubuntu instance from my external machine.

Comment: What's the deal with switching users? This part doesn't make sense. And why do you call this a reverse proxy? It sounds like you want to tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your service to bind to localhost:123 on the ubuntu box.

Add this to your ubuntu box's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` at the end:

`Match User lockeddown
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  AllowTcpForwarding yes
  PermitOpen 127.0.0.1:123
  ForceCommand /bin/false`

This will allow your user `lockeddown` to connect to your ubuntu box and forward port 123 only:

```
ssh -N -L 123:localhost:123 lockeddown@your-ubuntu-box
```

You could then access it via 'localhost:123':

```
telnet localhost 123
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do local port forwarding instead with something like:

`ssh -L 123:localhost:123 user@remote_machine`

Then on your machine you will be able to access it using localhost:123

Comment: Did this work fine for you? @Chaos